# How to know the exponent of a given function to be equal or greater than a given number

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

I have the following function: $f(x)=(0.9)^x$. I need to calculate for which $x$ it is true that $f(x) > 0.5$. How could I calculate it? Can I use a logarithm base 0.9?

$$
\log_{0.9}0.5=x
$$

If so, how could I use it to do the calculation?

Comment: You may find properties like $\log_b(x)=\frac{\log_c (x)}{\log_c (b)}$ helpful as you may not have a $\log_{0.9}$ key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $0.9=9/10$ so that you want $x$ such that $$\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^x>\frac{1}{2}\iff 2(9^x)>10^x\\\iff \log(2)+x\log(9)>x\log(10)\\\iff x<\frac{\log(2)}{\log(10)-\log(9)}$$
Note: the choice of log base doesn't matter here. It could be $e$ or $10$ as are fairly common, although you could choose base $21$ if you want or whatever.

As a note, recall that we have $$\log(b^x)=x\log(b),\qquad\log(ab)=\log(a)+\log(b)$$

Comment: base $10$ would work better as $\log 10=1$ so one less calculation to do

Comment: I see, thank you. I used 9/10 because I was following the definition of logarithm. Why is it that I can use any base, what's the foundation behind it?

Comment: You're just taking the log of both sides (in the process I show above), and it doesn't matter which base. This is because log is always increasing, so the inequality is preserved.

Comment: I see, thank you.